# Clarification about the behaviour of request_threaded_irq

Tags: multithreading, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I have scoured the web, but haven't found a convincing answer to a couple of related questions I have, with regard to the "request_threaded_irq" feature.

**Question1:**
Firstly, I was reading this article, regarding threaded IRQ's:

http://lwn.net/Articles/302043/

and there is this one line that isn't clear to me:

"Converting an interrupt to threaded makes only sense when the handler
 code takes advantage of it by integrating tasklet/softirq
 functionality and simplifying the locking."

I understand had we gone ahead with a "traditional", top half/bottom half approach, we would have needed either spin-locks or disable local IRQ to meddle with shared data. But, what I don't understand is, how would threaded interrupts simplify the need for locking by integrating tasklet/softirq functionality.

**Question2:** 
Secondly, what advantage (if any), does a request_threaded_handler approach have over a work_queue based bottom half approach ? In both cases it seems, as though the "work" is deferred to a dedicated thread. So, what is the difference ?

**Question3:** 
Lastly, in the following prototype:

```
int request_threaded_irq(unsigned int irq, irq_handler_t handler, irq_handler_t thread_fn, unsigned long irqflags, const char *devname, void *dev_id)
```

Is it possible that the "handler" part of the IRQ is continuously triggered by the relevant IRQ (say a UART receving characters at a high rate), even while the "thread_fn"(writing rx'd bytes to a circular buffer) part of the interrupt handler is busy processing IRQ's from previous wakeups ? So, wouldn't the handler be trying to "wakeup" an already running "thread_fn" ? How would the running irq thread_fn behave in that case ?

I would really appreciate if someone can help me understand this.

Thanks,
 vj

Comment: Kaiwan described details in his answer, which should worth a read.   https://stackoverflow.com/a/29250402/4123703

Answer (score 5):

For Question 2,
An IRQ thread on creation is setup with a higher priority, unlike workqueues.
In `kernel/irq/manage.c`, you'll see some code like the following for creation of kernel threads for threaded IRQs:

```
            static const struct sched_param param = {
                    .sched_priority = MAX_USER_RT_PRIO/2,
            };


            t = kthread_create(irq_thread, new, "irq/%d-%s", irq,
                               new->name);
            if (IS_ERR(t)) {
                    ret = PTR_ERR(t);
                    goto out_mput;
            }

            sched_setscheduler_nocheck(t, SCHED_FIFO, &param);
```

Here you can see, the scheduling policy of the kernel thread is set to an RT one (`SCHED_FIFO`) and the priority of the thread is set to `MAX_USER_RT_PRIO/2` which is higher than regular processes.

For Question 3,
The situation you described can also occur with normal interrupts. Typically in the kernel, interrupts are disabled while an ISR executes. During the execution of the ISR, characters can keep filling the device's buffer and the device can and must continue to assert an interrupt even while interrupts are disabled.

It is the job of the device to make sure the IRQ line is kept asserted till all the characters are read and any processing is complete by the ISR. It is also important that the interrupt is level triggered, or depending on the design be latched by the interrupt controller.

Lastly, the device/peripheral should have an adequately sized FIFO so that characters delivered at a high rate are not lost by a slow ISR. The ISR should also be designed to read as many characters as possible when it executes.

Generally speaking what I've seen is, a controller would have a FIFO of a certain size `X`, and when the FIFO is filled `X/2`, it would fire an interrupt that would cause the ISR to grab as much data as possible. The ISR reads as much as possible and then clears the interrupt. Meanwhile, if the FIFO is still `X/2`, the device would keep the interrupt line asserted causing the ISR to execute again.

Answer (score 2):

1. Previously, the bottom-half was not a `task` and still [could not block](http://lwn.net/Articles/239633/).  The only difference was that interrupts were disabled.  The *tasklet* or *softirq* allow different inter-locks between the driver's *ISR thread* and the user API (`ioctl()`, `read()`, and `write()`).
2. I think the `work queue` is near equivalent.  However, the *tasklet/ksoftirq* has a high priority and is used by all ISR based functionality on that processor.  This may give better scheduling opportunities.  Also, there is less for the driver to manage; everything is already built-in to the kernel's ISR handler code.
3. You must handle this.  Typically [*ping-pong*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_buffering) buffers can be used or a `kfifo` like you suggest.  The `handler` should be greedy and get all data from the UART before returning `IRQ_WAKE_THREAD`.

Comment: Another related question: Does disabling interrupts stop a threaded IRQ from running as well?

Answer (score 2):

For Question no 3, 
when an threadedirq is activated the corresponding interrupt line is masked / disabled. when the threadedirq runs and completes it enables it towards the end of the it. hence there won't be any interrupt firing while the respective threadedirq is running.

Answer (score 1):

The original work of converting "hard"/"soft" handlers to threaded handlers was done by Thomas Gleixner & team when building the [PREEMPT_RT Linux](https://rt.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page) (aka Linux-as-an-RTOS) project (it's not part of mainline).
To truly have Linux run as an RTOS, we cannot tolerate a situation where an interrupt handler interrupts the most critical rt (app) thread; but how can we ensure that the app thread even overrides an interrupt?? By making it (the interrupt) threaded, schedulable (SCHED_FIFO) and have a lower priority than the app thread (interrupt threads rtprio defaults to 50). So a "rt" SCHED_FIFO app thread with a rtprio of 60 would be able to "preempt" (closely enough that it works) even an interrupt thread. That should answer your Qs. 2.

Wrt to Qs 3:
As others have said, your code must handle this situation.
Having said that, pl note that a key point to using a threaded handler is so that you can do work that (possibly) blocks (sleeps). If your "bottom half" work is guaranteed to be non-blocking and *must* be fast, pl use the traditional style 'top-half/bh' handlers. 
How can we do that? Simple: don't use request_threaded_irq() just call request_irq() - the comment in the code clearly says (wrt 3rd parameter):

```
* @thread_fn: Function called from the irq handler thread
*          If NULL, no irq thread is created"
```

Alternatively, you can pass the IRQF_NO_THREAD flag to request_irq.

(BTW, a quick check with cscope on the 3.14.23 kernel source tree shows that request_irq() is called 1502 times [giving us *non-threaded* interrupt handling], and request_threaded_irq() [*threaded* interrupts] is explicitly called 204 times).