# How to use request_threaded_irq so that the interrupt handler is called while the threaded handler works?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, arm, interrupt

I am trying to write a simple interrupt handler for a GPIO in the linux kernel. I use `request_threaded_irq` to get an interrupt context handler, and a threaded handler.

My problem is that the work done by the threaded handler has a big impact on the timing of the calls to the interrupt handler.

The code to setup the interrupt is:

```
gpio_request(93, "test")
gpio_direction_input(93);
gpio_request(33, "mirror");
gpio_direction_output(33, 1);

request_threaded_irq(gpio_to_irq(93),
        interrupt_handler,
        threaded_interrupt_handler,
        IRQF_TRIGGER_RISING | IRQF_TRIGGER_FALLING | IRQF_TIMER,
        "test", NULL);
```

Here, I am simply requesting gpio 93 to fire an interrupt on rising and falling edges. I also request gpio 33 to use as a mirror, see below.

(In my setup, I put a clock source on gpio 93).

The code of the interrupt handler is this:

```
static irqreturn_t interrupt_handler(int irq, void *data)
{
    int state = gpio_get_value(93);
    gpio_set_value(33, state);
    return IRQ_WAKE_THREAD;
}
```

Here, the interrupt handler is simply mirroring gpio 93 input value as an output value for gpio 33. This allows me to monitor the effective rate of the calls to `interrupt_handler`.

Lastly, the threaded handler:

```
static irqreturn_t threaded_interrupt_handler(int irq, void *data)
{
    /* doing msleep here is apparently problematic... */
    msleep(1);
    return IRQ_HANDLED;
}
```

In the threaded interrupt handler, calling `msleep` (or actually performing work) is problematic: by looking with a scope at the gpio output 33, I can see that the `interrupt_handler` callback rate changes drastically when the `threaded_interrupt_handler` sleeps or perform too much work.

How can I setup/use `request_threaded_irq()` so that the interrupt handler is always called "on-time" even if the threaded handler as some big work to do?

Comment: Setup a semaphore between the ISR and threaded handler.  Only use `IRQ_WAKE_THREAD`, if the threaded guy has given the semaphore and there is no more work to do.  That said, this is odd.  You didn't supply a kernel version or any source that you may have investigated to see why the issue occurs.

Comment: A semaphore should be used to protect data, but there is no data involved here. kernel version is 3.13. I tried to make the question clear: why is the threaded interrupt handler changing the timing of the interrupt handler?

Comment: A semaphore may protect anything.  If you do a 'try' in the interrupt handler and it fails, then you return `IRQ_HANDLED`.  If it passes, then return `IRQ_WAKE_THREAD`.  The *thread* takes the semaphore (or whatever lock-free primitive you like). An *atomic_t* will probably work.

Answer (score 7):

I eventually understand what was happening. According to [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19650570/1183484), *the interrupt is masked* while processing the interrupt **and** the threaded interrupt handler.

So it seems I misunderstood the point of `request_threaded_irq`: it should really be used so that the interrupt handling is in a task scheduled by the scheduler.

For my needs, what I really wanted was simply a wait_queue. I remove the threaded interrupt handler for my code and changed the interrupt handler to something like:

```
static wait_queue_head_t wq;

static irqreturn_t interrupt_handler(int irq, void *data)
{
    int state = gpio_get_value(93);
    gpio_set_value(33, state);
    wake_up_interruptible(&wq);
    return IRQ_HANDLED;
}
```

Now, the interrupt handler is called with a correct timing!